# UITableViewCell custom subclass view not updated

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

In my custom table view cell subclass, the location of one of the textlabel depends on the content of an ivar (NSString). (i.e: if the NSString is the empty string, the location of the textlabel's frame is different).

The position if updated as follow:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    customOverlayCell *myCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomOverlayCell"];

    if ([buildingFName isEqual:@""])
    {
        CGRect titleLabelFrame = myCell.titleLabel.frame; 
        titleLabelFrame.origin.y  = 45;
        [myCell.titleLabel setFrame:titleLabelFrame];
    }

    return myCell;
}
```

I have removed parts of code that weren't relevant.

The result is that the layout of the first cells that appear on the screen are properly updated, but the layout of the views that appear after scrolling down aren't updated.

Am I not using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier properly? Or is anything else wrong?

Edit:

Solution from EJV:

```
CGRect titleLabelFrame = myCell.titleLabel.frame; 

if ([buildingFName isEqual:@""])
{
    titleLabelFrame.origin.y  = 45;
} else {
    titleLabelFrame.origin.y  = 37;
}

[myCell.titleLabel setFrame:titleLabelFrame];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the frame of the title label is dynamic, then when you dequeue a cell from the table view, the frame could be in either of the two states (when buildingFName is empty and when it has characters).  You need to make sure that you set the frame for when buildingFName is not empty.  That way, the title label's frame will always be set correctly.  So, you need code like this:

```
CGRect titleLabelFrame = myCell.titleLabel.frame;

if ([buildingFName isEqual:@""])
{ 
    titleLabelFrame.origin.y  = 45;
} else {
    // Change titleLabelFrame
}

[myCell.titleLabel setFrame:titleLabelFrame];
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. My programming is so bad. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, it would require subclassing the cell and implementing [UITableViewCell layoutSubviews] to properly lay out your subviews of the cell. This is how I did something similar for a switch table view cell:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGFloat const ESCFieldPadding = 10.0f;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    // call super layout
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // obtain widths of elements
    CGFloat contentWidth = self.contentView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat contentHeight = self.contentView.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat switchWidth = self.switchView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat switchHeight = self.switchView.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat labelWidth = contentWidth - (4 * ESCFieldPadding) - switchWidth;

    // correctly position both views
    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(ESCFieldPadding, 0.0f, 
                                      labelWidth, contentHeight);
    // it is needed to explicitly resize font as for some strange reason,
    // uikit will upsize the font after relayout
    self.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont labelFontSize]];

    CGRect switchFrame = self.switchView.frame;
    switchFrame.origin = CGPointMake(contentWidth - ESCFieldPadding - switchWidth,
                                     (contentHeight / 2) - (switchHeight / 2));
    self.switchView.frame = CGRectIntegral(switchFrame);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: I tried putting my layout modifications in - (void)layoutSubviews, but it didn't change anything. Fortunately, EJV found the answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try to disable autolayout from your cell

Comment: Thanks, but that question has been solved a year ago it seems!